# Swing: How to read graphic information underneath a component?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, graphics, effects

How could I "read" graphic information **underneath a component**
(let's say as **BufferedImage**)?

I want to make that component half-translucent (already done)
and apply graphic effects on underlying stuff, such as blur all
elements under that component (**but not the component itself**).

My approach is probable wrong:
I try to get graphic information from Graphics2D instance given to me
in the **paint(...)** method, but it's empty, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: is your component top-level (i.e., do you want to know what's on the desktop under a JFrame), or do you just want to know about components that are layered underneath the component?

If 1), then it's a simple matter to grab a screenshot with the [`java.awt.Robot`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) method [`createScreenCapture(Rectangle)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)); the `Rectangle` should be your window bounds in this case.

If 2), then if you have a reference to the component underneath, you can make use of the fact that [`paint(Graphics)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) doesn't care where the `Graphics` object came from. You can create a `BufferedImage`, call [`createGraphics()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics()) (in case a `Graphics2D` is expected), and pass the result to the `paint(Graphics)` method of the component that you want to capture.
Note that if the component is a container, it will paint its children also; this may or may not be what you want.